# My "myModal" div id is not calling in setTimeout Function using jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want to show poppup box if user sticks more than 10seconds in website, I tried with jquery settimeout function, it is not showing, please check this, I don't know where i went wrong. Here is my link also http://lotusvaluedevelopers.com/contactside.html,

If we click contact us, the popup will come, what I am trying to do, user sticks more than 10second in website, I need to trigger the popup automatically or any autotrigger function also available.

How to trigger the function after 10s using jquery trigger. because the slide toggle is not showing in online, i try with trigger

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#myModal').slideToggle();
    }, 1000);
  });
</script>
I tried with this code also no output
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myModal").trigger();
    },10);
});
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-box rotated">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg turned-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Contact Us</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">
            Contact Us
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form">
            <p> Send your message in the form below and we will get back to you as early as possible. </p>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name"> Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required maxlength="50">
            </div>

        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="btnContactUs">Post It! &rarr;</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For ten seconds, you need to apply 10000ms, not 1000ms. Aside from that there's basic validation errors in your HTML.

Comment: The code work in http://jsfiddle.net/n0rLck68/

Comment: I uploaded in server kindly check in given link http://lotusvaluedevelopers.com/contactside.html  it is not coming

Comment: just let me know how to trigger the function after 10seconds using jquery trigger. because the slide toggle is not showing in online, i try with trigger

Comment: The code work in snippet. So what is problem?

Comment: please check the given url, if you click the contact us,see the popup same thing i want to do in after page load 10 s, I think you understood the required, please see my below code also.

Comment: i have written like this also no output $("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myModal").trigger();
    },10);
});

Comment: check vishnu answer, please, this what i needed,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Bootstrap docs, if you want to manually show/display a modal, you will have to use `modal('show')` method. (More ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events)

Example:
`$('#myModal').modal('show')`

**In your case try doing the same:**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }, 10000);
});
```

> Time should be in ms, 10000ms = 10sec.

Comment: check now it is runinng in server , it is coming as per my requirement http://lotusvaluedevelopers.com/contactside.html and thanks for your explanation